# Array-based coding

Tags: arrays, xcode

How do you find the missing number in a given integer array of 1 to 100? I tried by calculating the sum of the series but how do I do this if I have more than one missing number or if the array has duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

All of your interview questions are going to have some trick.

The general solution that supports all of the nonsense they might throw at you is

```swift
Set(1...100).subtracting(array)
```